# Python: Creating chunks of files based on number of rows

Tags: python

I have a file with the following view:

```
ID Num1 Num2
1   1   2
1   2   4
1   3   6
2   4   8
2   5   10
3   6   12
3   7   14
3   8   16
3   9   18
4   10  20
5   11  22
5   12  24
```

I want to split the file into multiple files based on the condition that each file should not contain more than 3 ID values. So, in this case, their will two output files. 1st file should have the output:

```
1   1   2
1   2   4
1   3   6
2   4   8
2   5   10
3   6   12
3   7   14
3   8   16
3   9   18
```

While the second file should look like this:

```
4   10  20
5   11  22
5   12  24
```

But instead it generates, three files with the 2nd file as an empty file and 3rd file containing values of only ID=5.

Following code is written in python:

```
infile=open("Input.txt","r")
outfile=open("Output1.txt","w")

list_value=[] # Storing the values of 1st column
file=2 # Naming the file
value="" # 1st column value
for line in infile:
    value=line.split()[0] 
    if value in list_value:
        outfile.write(line)
    else:
        list_value.append(value)
        if (len(list_value)) < 4:
            outfile.write(line)
        elif (len(list_value))==4:
            outfile=open("Output"+str(file)+".txt","w")
            outfile.write(line)
            file=file+1
            list_value=[]
```

The code is working fine only for the first sequences but fails to work in the end.

Any commands for linux can also be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: you assume the IDs are sorted in the input file?

Comment: You should properly `.close()` your files.

Comment: Yes ID's are sorted in the file.

Comment: Closing the file helped. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last line in your code should be

```
list_value = [value]
```

instead of

```
list_value = []
```

since the file you open in the `elif` clause already contains ID `value`.